# Microsoft Forms auto refresh survey after user answers question

Tags: survey, intranet, postback, modern

I'm using Microsoft Forms to create an embedded survey on our home Intranet page.

I have a two column layout where, on the left, the user answers the question. On the right, the results are displayed. When a user answers, the results are not updated until the page refreshes.

Is there a way to force the webpart to refresh once a user answers the question?

Form web address:
https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=AXXXXXXXu0keilvrBp6UFvGlMXSkeH9VKgkwmfsvvMPFUQlBLWUpGMUxZUlBESUFXXXXXXXXXXXX

[image]

Comment: Great question... and i was also looking if there is a way to redirect the user to the responses after a survey or poll is submitted?

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this. The MS Modern webparts are very limited.